# VS2015 v120のプラットフォームでMFCを使いたい

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

Visual Studio 2015 Communityを使用しています。
MFCを使ったアプリを作っていますが、プラットフォームツールセットを「Visual Studio 2013 (v120)」に変更したところ、次のエラーが出ました。

```
fatal error C1083: include ファイルを開けません。'afxwin.h':No such file or directory
```

v120でMFCは使えないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[方法: ターゲット フレームワークおよびプラットフォームのツールセットを変更する](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ff770576.aspx)には

> 対象とするプラットフォーム ツールセットを変更するには、関連付けられたバージョンの Visual Studio または Windows プラットフォーム SDK がインストールされている必要があります。

と説明されています。その上で、WindowsプラットフォームSDKにはMFCが含まれていませんので、Visual StudioのProfessional以上のエディションかComunityエディションをインストールする必要があります。